# unused variable warning when variable is actually being used

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am given a warning in Xcode that a variable I am using, is not being used:

```
- (void)timerTicked:(id)sender {
  [timerButton setTitle:[self timerIsActive] ? @"Stop timer" : @"Start Timer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  if([self timerIsActive]) {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:timeEntry.startDate];
    double seconds = (int) interval % 60;
    double minutes = (int) interval / 60.0;
    double hours = (int) interval / 60.0 / 60.0;

    [timerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f hours %.0f minutes %.0f seconds", hours, minutes, seconds]];
  }
}
```

The variable reported not being used is `interval`.

Why is `interval` being reported as unused?

Comment: Whats the exact compiler output?

Comment: You're sure it's that instance of `interval`, and not some other variable declared `interval` elsewhere in the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. Try to clean the code and Analyze using shift commond B. -- AV

Comment: sigh - this did it. i feel like a noob! I had to re-analyze - not just build