# Unused variable error, even though variable is actually used - only when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have a weird error when trying to archive the project - it fails with `Unused variable` error.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
{
    NSString *requestId = ((NSHTTPURLResponse*)urlResponse).allHeaderFields[kRequestIdKey]; // Unused variable 'requestId'

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Requesting %@ %@ failed: %@, requestId: %@", urlRequest.HTTPMethod, urlRequest.URL.description, error, requestId); // requestId variable actually being used
    }

    // do stuff
}];
```

The thing is, it fails only when archiving - the project builds and runs just fine, and shows no warnings for unused variables.

In Build Settings, `Treat Warnings as Errors` is set to `NO` for both debug and release. Disabling `Unused Variables` warnings also does not help.

Cleaning / cleaning build folder / deleting derived data also does not help.

I tried Product > Analyze, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582890/unused-variable-warning-when-variable-is-actually-being-used) - it doesn't even show any warning there

I'm using Xcode 9.0, but I also tried Xcode 8.0 and the issue is still there.

Comment: There is some difference in your build settings between Debug (used for normal builds) and Release (used for archiving).

Comment: No, the settings for `Treat warnings as errors` and `Warnings - Unused variables` are identical

Comment: Have you checked other build settings for differences?

Comment: Which ones make a difference in this case?

Comment: No idea - but the fact that you're seeing a difference between normal (Debug) and archive (Release) builds would indicate that something is different. You'll need to take a look at them and figure out which. Just look for any setting with **<multiple values>**. When you have eliminated all which is impossible, then whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

Comment: Well, no idea why your build is ***Failing***, but I'm betting you have a redefinition for `NSLog()` - likely based on a `#ifndef DEBUG` - which is what causes the `Unused Variable`

Comment: @DonMag you are indeed correct